# For loop if sum two cells

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm trying to replicate this vba code to Google script:

```
    With ws1
        colF = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
        colG = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 4 To LastRow Step 1
        colF = .Cells(i, "F").Value
        colG = .Cells(i, "G").Value
          If colF + colG > 115 Then
             'copy rows etc
          End if
       Next
   End With
```

```js
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('ws1');
      var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
      var colF= sheet.getRange(6,4,lastRow)
      var colG= sheet.getRange(7,4,lastRow)
    
      for (var i=0; i <=lastRow; i++) {
         if (colF ++ colG > 115) {  
             //copy rows etc
         }
      }
```

Can you help me find the correct approach?
Thanks

**EDIT**

This is the error

*"if (colF ++ colG > 115) { " error.*

I solved with `if (colF +++ colG > 115) {`.

My target is to sum for each row two values ​​that are on the same row but in two different columns.

If the result meets the ">115" condition, then copy rows.

I can't find the correct syntax, I can't find the values ​​in the columns

Comment: What problems are you facing? What error messages? What's actual versus expected behavior?

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on row "if (colF ++ colG > 115) { ".

Comment: That should say `colF + colG`. I'm not sure why you're using `/++`

Comment: Please add the information to the question and remove your comment. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Done and I added my target

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variables colF and colG are ranges and not specific values or row numbers, so you can't add them or compare them to a number.

To speed up iterating through the rows, grab the entire data set, get the values, then iterate through the resulting 2D array.

Also, since you are iterating through just the data set, the first row of your data will be index 0.   Keep this in mind when working with the data or pasting it somewhere, you need to convert the dataSet index to a spreadsheet row.

```
function columns(){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('ws1');
  var startRow = 4;
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var numRows = lastRow - startRow;
  var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();//the number of columns you want to copy 

  //this gets a 2D array of the values from your starting row to the last row and from col 1 to the last col.
  var dataSetValues = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, lastCol).getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < lastRow; i++){
    //get the value of row i, col F
    //arrays are index based, to get a column from a row, subtract 1 from the column number
    //in this case Col F is Col 6, so it's index is 5.
    let fVal =  dataSetValues[i][5];

    //get the value of row i, col G    
    let gVal = dataSetValues[i][6];
    
    //add the two together
    // the + before each var forces app script to treat as a number, it is notoriously bad for randomly treating values as strings
    let sum = +fVal + +gVal;
        
    if (sum > 115) {  
      //get row i values, this is a 1D array of the column values
      let row = dataSetValues[i];
      //do something with row
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying your script. In VBA The loop starts from row n4 , I've to sum two values in two columns. I am noticing that the execution of your script is quite slow

Comment: Without seeing your data, I has to approximate everything.   If you want to start at row 4, start the loop with i = 4.  I will update the answer to show a faster way of doing it.

Comment: I edited the script with for (var i = 4, i <= lastRow, i++){.
In my simulation there are only 4 rows to check

Comment: I just updated my answer to speed it up.   If you pull the entire data set at once, and loop through the resulting 2D array, it should speed up significantly.

Comment: Sorry but I receive  TypeError: Cannot read property '5' of undefined, but  column F and column G aren't blank.

Comment: I've edited with var numRows = lastRow  - startRow + 1; and for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++){.
It works. This is a correct method?

Comment: Yes, that works.  Sorry I wasn't able to test it fully.

Comment: Thanks, very kind